# Is there a label/goto in python?

Tags: batch-file, python

We can use `goto` and `:label` in batch.
Is there anything like it in Python?

Comment: @jonno Are you saying "Go To Considered Harmful"? :) http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html for those who don't know their history.

Comment: What does `goto` or `:label` do in batch?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: nooooooooooooooo.

Comment: Never think about that again.

Comment: I wish the folks at superuser would make at least a cursory check for exact duplicates before migrating.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no `goto` or label or other equivalent in vanilla python.

Your best bet is to stick with regular control flow statements (e.g. `if`, `else if`, `else`, `for`, `while`, `break`, `continue`, ...) and functions (which add `return` to the list of control flow statements as well ...)

Comment: `try`, `except`, `finally` are a few more . . . Python's got lots of options :-)